# How to limit number of logins when domain controller is unavailable

Tags: login, active-directory, windows-domain

is there any way to set an AD group policy to limit the number of logins when a domain controller is unavailable (can't be reached)?
I have 50 laptops in my company that are members of the domain and are intended to be used to work from home. The problem is that users often don't bring their laptops to work (in order to connect to LAN to update group policy, some custom software, etc.) for long periods of time, which could cause some security issues.
So I am looking for either some group policy setting to limit the number of logins when DC is unavailable (or to limit usage based on the number of days without communication with DC). Is there an option, or maybe some 3rd party software that can do this?

Comment: Do the laptops not have any form of VPN for reaching the domain controllers from outside?

Comment: Yes, we use Checkpoint VPN, but I don't have the option to force users to use it all the time.

Comment: Are you looking to force users to connect their device to the domain or kick insecure devices which remain unpatched? There are group policies, and software, that will NOT allow insecure devices to connect to an AD domain. It seems the solution to this problem is to have a VPN, and allow devices connected to the VPN, to log into the domain allowing the WSUS to deploy patches.

Comment: I am trying to force users to connect the device to the domain. I have checkpoint VPN but I can't force users to use it. That is why "simply" denying login/blocking the internet (or something similar) is the only solution to make them comply :)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a Group Policy that would automatically expire cached credentials. However, they *could* be manually deleted from the Registry somewhat easily (I'll add the exact location later). Not aware of any existing tools, but this could be done using a custom startup script (itself deployed via GPO).

As an alternative, you might set up an "always on" IKEv2 VPN using the built-in IPsec support in Windows Firewall, solely for accessing a domain controller.

Comment: We don't use Windows firewall, we use Symantec Endpoint Security. But that registry entry can be interesting if it could be set via GPO to run every X startup.